# convert a Windows solution into windows docker containers

Tags: windows, docker

I'm completely new to docker and I’m not a developer. I was asked to port a windows applications solution to windows containers.

I have an application that uses

- A custom service
- .Net application

This first two components need to run on same container and I need to modify the window registry of the container to give parameters for them to run.

Then I also have

- A webservice WSDL running on IIS
- A COM+ application

These two components also need to be configured using windows registry and to run on the same container.

Finally, I need some kind of repository this could be just a drive that both containers need to access so they can generate some files there, and the .Net application of the first container needs to read from an SQL remote database.

My question is, if this is possible and can be done.

Comment: Your question is totally unclear, what do you mean by this? "These two components also need to be configured using windows registry and to run on the same container." Try reading some docker tutorials and then the documentation to be familiar with how does docker work. Or try to clarify your question.

Comment: I've been reading docker documentation for several days and also tutorials. All tutorials are very simple run a server core with IIS and run your asp.net application, but what I have is a much more complex solution, that uses also a COM+ Application, uses a customized service, both that need to be configured through windows registry (you know regedit). So my question is: Can this be done or is it just plain foolish thinking this could be ported to a windows container to run on docker for windows?

Comment: If what you are intending to is able to run in Linux, then you can get it, otherwise you cannot get that (except if you used wine may on linux, I am not sure).

Comment: Sorry maybe the title isn't clear, I'm talking about docker for Windows and that is why I'm referring to windows containers

Comment: Docker for windows is nothing more than a mini virtual machine which implements Linux and then runs Docker inside that mini Linux environment.